# Android: Code to catch every possible type of "Enter" key (hard and soft)?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Good day!

I have an Android app (v2.3.3 and up) that allows you to search via an `EditText` control. I'm using the following code to detect when the user is done and either presses a hardkey or a softkey to perform the search:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_box);    
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
            (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) 
        {
                performSearch();              
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

This, apparently, does not catch EVERY possible way of expressing "Enter" as a beta tester just told me the "Enter" key on their HTC Evo soft keyboard doesn't do anything. The search hardkey (magnifying glass) works, but this code isn't catching the event from the soft keyboard.

Reading some posts, most answers to this type of question contain some, or all, of the logic above. I've also read that HTC does some keyboard stuff differently.

Does anyone have some bullet-proof code for detecting "Enter" input on ANY device?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I already had this same problem. Remove the check for the actionId, just check for `event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` in your if statement:

```
@Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        {
                performSearch();              
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work. `event` is `null` so it died with a `NullPointerException`. I'm currently testing against a 2.3.3 device.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
         performSearch();              
         return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think textchangelistener can capture enter key, try this

```
        commentt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // if enter is added to your CharSequence 
            // { 
            //      do search

            // }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```